# Javascript % operator in IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to debug some pre-existing JS code and I can't work out what exactly this line of code does, can someone help

```
if(value % 7 == 0){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks if 'value' is divisible by 7 by giving the remainder i.e 'value % 7' gets the remainder of 'value' by dividing it by 7 if it is equal to 0 ('==7') it will be true.

'%' is called the Modulus operator see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9f59bza0(v=vs.94).aspx for more info

Answer (score 2):

It checks if the `value` is completely divisible by 7

**Remainder (%)**

> The remainder operator returns the first operand modulo the second operand, that is, var1 modulo var2, in the preceding statement, where var1 and var2 are variables. The modulo function is the integer remainder of dividing var1 by var2.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

`%` is [Remainder operatot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

```
value % 7
```

give the remainder when number is divided by a number in you case value is divided by 7.

> Thumb Rule. `value % some_number` will always return a value between range `[0,some_number-1]`.

so `if statement` will execute if remainder is 0.

```
if(value % 7 == 0){...}
```